# How best to store information about inheritance in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, inheritance, orm

Let's say I have 3 types of objects: `Animal`, `Dog`, and `Poodle`. I want to store the data in these objects as documents in mongodb.

Let's say my document for `Animal` looks like:

```
{
    "name": ...
}
```

My document for `Dog` looks like:

```
{
    "name": ...,
    "barkFile": ...
}
```

And my document for `Poodle` looks like:

```
{
    "name": ...,
    "barkFile": ...,
    "haircut": ...
}
```

When looking up suggestions about storing objects of different types, pretty much everyone seems to say use a type field. That would work fine for different types of animals, like this:

```
{
    "_type": "cat",
    "name": ...,
    "meowFile": ...
}

{
    "_type": "dog",
    "name": ...,
    "barkFile": ...
}
```

But it doesn't allow me to store 3 levels of inheritance. Basically I want to do something like this:

```
doc1 = {
    "_type": "animal",
    "name": ...
}

doc2 = {
    "_type": "animal.dog",
    "name": ...,
    "barkFile": ...
}

doc3 = {
    "_type": "animal.dog.poodle",
    "name": ...,
    "barkFile": ...,
    "haircut": ...
}
```

I don't want to do it exactly like this, as I want to be able to do something like `db.animals.find({type: 'animal.dog'})` and get both doc2 and doc3. I'd rather not reinvent the wheel, so if this problem has been dealt with before (which I suspect it has), I'd appreciate someone directing me towards the solutions other people have come up with. Thanks.

Comment: I would start here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply store the types and subtypes in an array like this:

```
doc1 = {
    "_type": ["animal"],
    "name": ...
}

doc2 = {
    "_type": ["animal","dog"],
    "name": ...,
    "barkFile": ...
}

doc3 = {
    "_type": ["animal","dog","poodle"],
    "name": ...,
    "barkFile": ...,
    "haircut": ...
}
```

Using this model, the query `db.data.find({_type:"dog"})` returns both doc2 and doc3.