# How do I map polymorphic Java classes to MongoDB entities using Spring?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I am relatively new to Spring. I'm trying to implement a simple CRUD RESTful API for MongoDB. I'm having issues with mapping annotations when it comes to polymorphic classes.

Here's my Employee class that holds a list of Allocations. The idea is that an employee can have multiple allocations at once. An Allocation could either be a training or a department.

```java
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String empCode;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<Allocation> allocations;

    // Getters, setters and Constructor
}
```

Here's the Allocation class.

```java
public class Allocation {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private LocalDate startDate;
    private LocalDate endDate;
    private String location;
}
```

And here are the Department and Training classes.

```java
public class Training extends Allocation {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String courseName;
}
```

```java
public class Department extends Allocation {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String deptName;
}
```

How do I map the above classes using Spring annotations? When I retrieve an Employee, I want the JSON to have an array of Allocations that include both Training Programs and Departments.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57643603/no-table-is-being-created-neither-the-restcontroller-url-is-working/57643722#57643722

Comment: Just create a repository, service and controller. Then you should good to go.

Comment: @ConstantinBeer I know how to do that to a simple entity. But got no idea on how to do the mapping where there are polymorphic classes like in my example.

Comment: Oh I think I got your question wrong. Know I got it. Sorry :)

Comment: Maybe you try something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34560183/how-best-to-store-information-about-inheritance-in-mongodb

Comment: Using relationship with mongodb is usually only trouble